# ESelectionService not working on receiving a message

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

I am using Eclipse 4.2 Juno, Java 1.6. I have two parts in my application. One part is registering the SelectionChangedListener:

```
@Inject
private ESelectionService selectionService;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    TreeViewer bsTreeViewer = new TreeViewer(tabFolder, SWT.BORDER);
    /* some other stuff */
    // Event declaration
    bsTreeViewer.addSelectionChangedListener(new SelectionChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void selectionChanged(SelectionChangedEvent event) {
            if( selectionService != null ) {
                 selectionService.setSelection(((IStructuredSelection)event.getSelection()).getFirstElement());
            }
        }
    });
}
```

This Listener is called correctly. The first selected Element is of the right type, too.

I another part I am setting up the receiving end:

```
@Inject
public void setBS(@Named(IServiceConstants.ACTIVE_SELECTION) @Optional BS bs) {
    if (bs == null) {
      /* implementation not shown */
    } else {
      /* implementation not shown */
    }
}
```

However, nothing is received on this end of the pipe. What am I doing wrong or how could I debug this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code above looks fine, but try to check the following issues:

- check if the receiver object is created - if not, it won't receive an event
- check if the receiver object is created by eclipse framework (for example if it is element of application model such as part, handler it is for sure created by the framework) - if not, the framework (selection service) does not know about the receiver object and cannot notify it

Comment: Somehow, my SVN Repo was broken. My reciever object was not called. I just reverted to an earlier state and now it is working again.